# QGIS geolocate a csv (insert point for each record manually in map)

Tags: qgis, geolocation

I have a CSV with data (no location, no lat/long). I need to load that CSV into QGIS and create a point for each feature.

I've trying for an hour without success..

I guess there must be a way to create a new empty SHP, upload CSV data into the SHP somehow and after that assign one point in the map for each element..but I can't find a way to do this in QGIS..

Comment: Quick Shot: Try Layer > add Layer > Add Vektorlayer and choose your .csv as source. This imports the table data. Assigning a location to your data is another  problem I have no quick answer to.

Comment: My approach: I imported the csv to a postgis table and added a geometry colum with the same point (wherever) for every element. After that I am moving the points where I want to using QGIS.

Comment: Are you looking to put the points in a specific location or can they be located anywhere as long as they have a coordinate?

Comment: I am loking to put them in their location. I have churches, schools, buildings etc, but I only have their names and I have to geolocate them.

Comment: @Egidi do you have addresses for these locations, or are you going to digitize them manually?

Comment: @mapBaker I need to digitize them manually. No addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following in similar situations:

- Open your CSV file in OpenOffice/Excel and add an extra, named column. Fill the column with sequential numbers (e.g. 0-200) using the appropriate auto fill.
- Import the CSV with `Layer > Add layer... > Add Delimited Text Layer...` with the `No geometry (attribute only table)` option selected.
- Zoom to your area of interest (I assume you have an aerial image or similar) and create a polygon over or close beside it – whatever will make the final step easiest. You can create a temporary scratch layer for this step.
- Use the `Vector > Research Tools > Regular Points...` tool, with your temporary polygon as an `Import Boundary Layer`. For grid spacing, set `Use this number of points` to your requirements (e.g. 200). Output and add the results to the project.

[image]

- Discard the temporary polygon.
- Perform a join between your CSV layer and the new point layer with `Layer > Layer Properties... > Joins` using the ID column in the point layer and the numbered column in your CSV as the `Join field`.
- Label the layer to help identify what they should represent in your area of interest, edit the layer and drag the points to their desired location.  `Save As...` the point layer when complete.

Not an ideal solution, but until QGIS has an option for adding geometry to non-spatial CSVs it may speed things up for you...

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am finally using a similar workaround: I add the CSV to PostGIS and in the Geometry Column I add in every record a point (Located in the middle of the are of interest). Same point for each record. After that I start draging the points to the desired location.

Comment: @Egidi I think that's your best path forward... similarily, you could create a spreadsheet with the locations and addresses, convert to CSV, then geocode them using the MMQGIS google geocoder...